# Custom Template in PushPin

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

Howdy,
I want to generate several location of pushpins on a seperate layer over a map. Those PushPins shall represent places at this very coordinate. Thus they should show some additional information which should be visible once the user taps/touches the Pushpin.

This whole solution is solely code based ( adding of the pushpins ).

I already here on sa that I should put an invisible button behind the pushpins - but I'm not quite sure how I should do that.

It would be great if somebody has a hint which'll bring me forward!

Thanks

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PushpinControlTemplate2">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        MinHeight="10"
                                        MinWidth="29">
                <Hyperlinkbutton HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{binding}" Click="clicker" Margin="0"/>
            </Grid>

            <Polygon Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                 Points="0,0 29,0 0,29"
                                 Width="29"                             
                                 Height="29"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is my code which I use so far,  the function clicker is defined, however I always the error 'AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE [Line: 5 Position: 98]'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [Pushpin-Styles in Bing Maps for the Windows Phone](http://jkebeck.wordpress.com/2010/11/17/pushpin-styles-in-bing-maps-for-the-windows-phone/) post should tell you everything you need to know about styling pushpins.

Comment: The remaining question would be how I could set the 'ContentTemplate' Attribute in C# code to the corresponding DataTemplate

Comment: Either set it as a resource and then load from there, e.g. `myPushPin.ContentTemplate = (ContentTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["TemplateKey"];` or deserialize it from XAML, e.g. `myPushPin.ContentTemplate = (ContentTemplate)XamlLoader.Load(templateString);`

Comment: If you are using **MergedDictionaries**, you can make this way: `myPushPin.Template = (ControlTemplate)App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0]["TemplateKey"];`